# VBA function to tell machine not to display certain variables

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, exists

I was wondering if there was a way to tell excel not to display some variables if the VLookup function couldn't find anything.

Here's roughly what my code does: take some numbers in another excel workbook by looking them up, compare that value from the previous year and take the difference, display that difference in another spreadsheet, all in one big merged cell.
Some excerpts from my code:

```
cashO = Val(Application.VLookup("cash" & "*", Workbooks("creditreport.csv").ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F199"), 4, False))
```

Then the difference    `cash = Round(cashN - cashO, 0)`

Then the Display: `MergedCell.Value = "Cash increased by" & cash`

But I dont want to display cash if it couldnt find cash in the first place (if this is the case, cash = 0 both when cash couldnt be found and when the change is null).

I was thinking of creating an array with all my variables (cash, ...) and then loop through it. But I couldn't find anything online on "if not found dont display anything".

Best,

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if else statement to check the value of cash and write the value if cash has a value and some other message like "no change" or "no previous value" if that's the case.

```
if cash = 0
    MergedCell.Value = "No Change"
Else
    MergedCell.Value = "Cash increased by" & cash
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just check if the function returns an error:

```
if iserror(Application.VLookup("cash" & "*", Workbooks("creditreport.csv").ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F199"), 4, False)) then
    cash = 0
else
    cashO = Val(iserror(Application.VLookup("cash" & "*", Workbooks("creditreport.csv").ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F199"), 4, False))

    ....other statements for whatever...
end if
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! If I dont want vba to display cash at all if it is not found in the other document, then I believe I would need to replace your    `cash = 0`  with something along the lines of  `cash = "" ``

Comment: I would suggest to avoid mixed data types with the same variable - i.e. I'm guessing you've defined cash as an integer or other number type. "" is an empty string and not a number. If you don't want to just handle the output in the If statement, but do it later on, then perhaps have a Boolean cashExists and have "cashExists = False" in place of "cash = 0" and "cashExists = True" in the else part. Then after the if, you can do "If cashExists then .... else ..... end if" to format your output later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you, that you mean that `VLookup` didn't find a match for "cash" , if that's the case you need error-handling.
If that's the case, try the code below:

```
Sub VLookup_Test()

On Error Resume Next    
cashO = Val(Application.VLookup("cash" & "*", Workbooks("creditreport.csv").ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F199"), 4, False))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "cashO not found" '
    ' Do your actions if cashO not found with VLookup

End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```